# Java difference

Tags: java, parsing

Hi I'm just beginner in Java and I don't undestand one thing what's the difference between this two codes:

```
System.out.println("Write a number: ");
int a = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

System.out.println("Write a number: ");
int b = sc.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

In `nextLine()` if you input number values that it will consider as String.
Then it is parsed to `Integer` and stored in `int a`

In `nextInt()` the entered numerical value is considered `Int` and stored in `int b`